# Markers are not displaying on Google map in flutter

Tags: flutter, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I am fetching data from server and show markers by given data here is the below code, please tell me where i am mistaking..

```
markers: markers,
                myLocationEnabled: true,
                //circles: mCircle,
                onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
                  _controller = controller;

                  _nearbyModelResponse.response.forEach((element) {
                    markers = Set.from([
                      Marker(position: LatLng(
                          double.parse(element.latitude),
                          double.parse(element.longitude)),
                          markerId: MarkerId(element.pcc),
                          icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarker),
                    ]);
                    //   marker.add();
                  });
                },
```

Comment: you create `markers` inside a `forEach` loop so after looping (for example 100 markers) your `markers` will still have one marker - the last one from `_nearbyModelResponse.response`

Comment: Could you please give me solution?

Comment: you need to call `Set.add` method inside the loop

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom function `_onMapCreated` outside your `build` method and then pass that to the `onMapCreated` inside the `GoogleMap` widget:

```
final Map<String, Marker> _markers = {};

Future<void> _onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller) async {
    final _nearbyModelResponse = await {your method to fetch data from server}
    setState(() {
      _markers.clear();
      for (final element in _nearbyModelResponse.response) {
        final marker = Marker(
          markerId: MarkerId(element.pcc),
          position: LatLng(element.lat, element.lng),
          icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarker,
        );
        _markers[element.pcc] = marker;
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Markers Sample'),
        ),
        body: GoogleMap(
          onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
          initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
            target: const LatLng(0, 0),
            zoom: 2,
          ),
          markers: _markers.values.toSet(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```